# Do Updating patches updates magento version itself..?

Tags: patches, ce-1.9.2.2

Need to confirm if we update Magento patches, will it update megento version itself or not..?
Forexample if we have version 1.9.1.1 and i update patches into it, will it update the magento version to 1.9.2.2 after installing patches..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer :No

If you apply a patch it'll only add some extra features/bug fixes. It'll not update the magento version.

Comment: ok and is there some possibility that magento upgrades by itself, i mean there is some auto setting from backend, which upgrades magento ..
I am asking this because i have a site,it was on 1.9.1.1, i havent upgraded that, just updated patches into it.. 
And after 2 week i realized that the version is changed to 1.9.2.2..

How is it possible..?

Comment: you may update the magento version by downloader

Comment: If possible can you please explain how..? and which downloader..?

Comment: check this http://www.hostknox.com/tutorials/magento/upgrade-with-connect-manager